# How can we install CKAN on Windows using IDE?

Tags: ckan

I wanted to install CKAN using IDE such as Eclipse+ Pydev on Windows. Is there any documentation/Steps for the same ? How will we connect Apache Solr and PostgreSQL when using Eclipse + Pydev IDE ?

What dependencies may be required to make it work?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the connection you see between Eclipse and CKAN? Are you doing CKAN development?

Answer (score 1):

Windows is not a supported platform for the service, according to [the documentation](https://ckan.org/download-and-install/).

However, if you *must* have a Windows machine, you can follow the [Docker compose](https://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-docker-compose.html) installation guide that CKAN provides.

Comment: During upgrading of CKAN using https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/maintaining/upgrading/upgrade-package-to-patch-release.html
The upgradation process mentioned here is for Ubuntu while my source install for CKAN is on CentOs. How can I make it work on Centos ? (the packages and all to download in short)